# After get time exception how I will restart web driver and continue script running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have given a timeout for driver.get() by below ways

```
self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

then Tried below code 

try :
    driver.get(url)
    print("URL successfully Accessed")
except TimeoutException as e:
    print("Page load Timeout Occured. Quiting !!!")
    pass
```

Problem is here 10 links are running , If one link occurs TimeoutException then next link not opening by driver.get().
I have below way to close driver and restart again.

```
except TimeoutException as e:
        print("Page load Timeout Occured. Quiting !!!")
        driver.close()
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
        pass
```

but, unfortunately result are same. How can I restart my driver and keep continue opening script ?

Answer (score 0):

For restarting browser try to do same like you do in your before scenario.
Something like: driver=new ChromeDriver(options);

Answer (score 0):

I code mostly in Java. So snippet is in Java below.
When you hit the TimeoutException, you close the driver. Since there is just one browser open, the driver quits(Session ends). Therefore you need to create a new instance of ChromerDriver. You can do this by checking for a session exception.

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println(("Getting Page " + i));
                driver.get("http://www.google.com");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                if(i==2) {
                    throw new org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException();
                }
            }

            catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e) {
                System.out.println(("Page load Timeout Occured. Quiting !!!"));
                driver.close();
            }
            
            catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException e) {
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
        }
```